Integral equation involving convolution
While working on a mini-project, I have the following sub-problem: Suppose $g$ and $p$ are given functions, and $p$ has the property $\int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x) dx = 1$. We are free to impose whatever conditions we want on $g$. I want to find a function $f$ such that the following holds:
$$
g(x) \big(p(x) - 1 \big) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)p(x-y) dy
$$
I first assumed that $g(x) = c$ was constant, and found that $f(x) = g(x) \delta(x) - g(x) = c( \delta(x) - 1 )$ was a solution. I now want to remove the assumption that $g$ is constant as this isn't very interesting for my problem. However I cannot make any progress on this. Is this even solvable when we remove the condition that $g$ is constant?

There is maybe a simplification that you can make, let $h(x)=g(x)(p(x)-1)$. Then the problem is one of deconvolution

Just spitballing here, but sometimes you can build a solution from the ground up. Can you show that operator $g \mapsto f$ is linear over $\mathbb{R}$? Perhaps you can work out a solution when $g(x) = x$, then by induction (maybe involving integration by parts), work out a solution for $x^n$, for natural $n$. Then you could put these results together to have a solution for any real analytic function $g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$.

Haha, I'm probably just reinventing the Fourier wheel with my idea, @YvesDaoust. Your suggestion makes perfect sense, assuming everything converges.
